# C++ Create vector or list from argument parameter packs

Tags: c++, vector, c++14, variadic-templates, c++17

I am looking for a solution, to compose arguments of `User` objects into an iterable `std::vector` or `std::list`

```
auto user_group = create_user_group(User(), User(), User(), User());
```

Example

```
template <typename ...Users>
auto create_user_group(Users&&... users)
{
    return std::vector<Users...>{std::forward<Users>(users)...};
}
```

Error

```
error: wrong number of template arguments (4, should be at least 1)
  return std::vector<Users...>{std::forward<Users>(users)...};
```

Comment: So... `std::vector<User, User, User, User>`?

Comment: All vector elements have same single type. Your variadic template is pointless.

Comment: @liliscent User is a parent class interface

Comment: @StoryTeller Yes, exactly

Comment: No, not exactly. You are supposed to specify the vector element type once

Comment: `std::vector` supports a single type `T` only.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If "Users" have different types then you need a type list. Fortunately, C++ has [tuple](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/utility/tuple/tuple_size) that can be used as a type list:

```
template <typename ...Users>
decltype(auto)
create_user_group(Users&&... users) {
  return std::make_tuple(std::forward<Users>(users)...);
}
```

[**Live Demo**](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/957d807163d11076)

Answer (score 4):

You need to separate a single argument to pass to `std::vector`:

```
template <typename User, typename ...Users>
auto create_user_group(User &&user, Users&&... users)
{
    return std::vector<std::decay_t<User>>{
        std::forward<User>(user), std::forward<Users>(users)...
    };
}
```

Comment: *+1* for the fix. But honestly, this is a moot exercise. The OP mentioned (in a comment) it's a base class interface... So the very next step is *"why are my objects not of the correct type?"*

Comment: It would be better to also remove cv-qualifier, otherwise your vector might have const element type, which is ill-formed. But honestly, using forwarding ref in this way is usually very suspicious.

Comment: @StoryTeller that comment came later. In that case it's just industrial-grade object slicing indeed.

Comment: @liliscent done. It does not seem so to me, since I'm just hooking onto the first type to deduce the vector's argument, but still want it to perfect-forward unaffected.